# converting special characters with html_entity_decode not working

Tags: php, character-encoding, decode, fpdf, decoder

I've got a php site where I export some data into a pdf file. The site uses fpdf to create the pdf file but some special characters doesn't show corretly in the created pdf file.

[image: Example of the error]

The tricky thing is that some special characters are printed correctly while others aren't. The default_charset of the site is "iso-8859-1" and the php files are coded in "ANSI". I also printed the array with the info (that I get from the database) and it's ok. So, I guess it's something with the fpdf? But It's strange that the same special character is printed corretly in some places and incorrectly in others.

Thank you :)

EDIT:

I've found out it's in this piece of code that the strings get bad encoded:

```
foreach ($this->relatorioData['Roteiro'] as $label => $value) {
            $this->Cell(55, 4, html_entity_decode($label), 0, 0, 'L', false);
            $this->Cell(95, 4, html_entity_decode($value), 0, 1, 'L', false);
        }
```

The strings are alright until the html_entity_decode where only some of them loose the special characters. Do you know what could do this? Should I use other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've found my answer. I needed to change this:

```
html_entity_decode($text)
```

To this:

```
html_entity_decode($label, ENT_COMPAT, 'ISO-8859-1')
```

This way all my stringd were decoded right.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into problems like this with FPDF, too. I searched all over before finding that this is actually addressed right in the [FPDF FAQ](http://www.fpdf.org/en/FAQ.php) (question/answer 3 as of this writing). There are a number of potential solutions in there depending on one's needs. The options cited there are:

- Use PHP's [utf8_decode() function](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php)
  `$str = utf8_decode($str);`
- Use PHP's [iconv() function](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)
  `$str = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $str);`
- Those who need characters "outside windows-1252" are directed to [a tutorial on adding new fonts and encodings](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto7.htm), or [tFPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/?go=script&id=92)